# Where to put external libraries

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm currently working on a static library in C++. My library uses externel libraries (precompiled). The question is; where should I put these external libraries? I just want to adapt to a common scheme for the directory structure.

Currently, my directory structure looks like this:

```
build   // Object files
include // Header files
lib     // Compiled library
src     // Source directory
test    // Test sources
tools   // Helpful scripts etc.
```

Comment: External libraries in what form? Header-only? Precompiled? Sources?

Comment: This depends on the operating system. What's your target? Windows, Linux and macOS have completely different approaches to handling this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Precompiled

Comment: @tadam Windows is the target (I've set up the libraries on Linux already. I just installed them (using "make install"). A similar approach on Windows would be practical but I can't find out where to install the libraries to (I don't think Windows has a library directory?))

Comment: I'd say just put them *somewhere*, and specify the location at build time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, external libraries are stored *externally*. i.e. outside of the project.

Different systems have different conventions. On POSIX systems for example, the library archives are typically stored in /usr/lib and headers in /usr/include. Such external libraries are typically installed using a package manager provided by the system. The downside of using system provided libraries (besides their location and management being system specific) is that sometimes you don't have much control over the version that you get. The upside is the benefit of sharing the libraries through dynamic linking.

There are cross-platform package managers for libraries as well, which work well with static linking, and allow for using specific version of a library. Such package managers also have their own convention of where they download the libraries.

Comment: I think this means "how do I bundle third-party pre-compiled libraries with my code for distribution?"

Answer (score 1):

Using a directory called `external` or `third_party` is quite common in many projects.